# FilterExpression to return exact value from TextBox instead of LIKE

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm working on a table presented within a GridView through a ObjectDataSource. I've also got a dropdown, a textfield and a button to enable filtering the table in the GridView. 
This is the code I am using to enable filtering:

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Name")
    {

        ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Name LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' ";

    }

 else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Result")
    {
        ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "convert(Result,'System.String')LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'";
    }
```

Now I noticed that in the case of the Result column if I search for 0 it shows all the results with a 0 in it, so 10,20,30 etc. instead of just the 0 entries. 
I have tried to use == instead of LIKE but it didn't work. Any suggestions how to make sure the Result filter only returns the EXACT value of the TextBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete *%* marks. It will give you strictly equal values
Instead of *Like(%'TEXT'%)* use *Like('TEXT')*

Comment: Nice that it helped you